# Find point on sphere given radius, center and 3D position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

In unity, I have built a game where I can place models using the mouse cursor (by dragging them to the scene). What I want is to be able to keep the distance between models unified, i.e. every model would be 10 units away of the model before it.

If it was a 2D problem it would be easy, by just calculating the angle between the center and the current mouse position and placing the model with x=r*cos(a), y=r*sin(a).

But I am not sure how to calculate it in 3D. As far as I know, there is another angle I need to calculate but how can I do it?

I have a position in 3D space, a center point and the desired distance, and I want to get is a new position that is in the direction of the original point but on the sphere it self (the original position can be in/out of the sphere)

Sorry for my bad English, but I hope it was clear enough what is my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand how you will get the coordinates of the mouse point in 3D, but if the sphere center is `(Xc, Yc, Zc)` and your point is `(X, Y, Z)`, the projected point is

```
(Xc + a (X - Xc), Yc + a (Y - Yc), Zc + a (Z - Zc))
```

where

```
a = R / √((X - Xc)² + (Y - Yc)² + (Z - Zc)²).
```

You don't need to use angles.

Comment: Wow this is so simple and elegant solution, I have been learning math for the past 4 month and never saw this formula. Thank a lot

Comment: @SagiZiv: you simply draw a vector from the center to the point and adjust its length to be R.